# Query only changing last record value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have table in sql-server wiith XML datatype. I want to change the value of one of the attribute. The table looks like:

```
id--------version-------XMLdata
1---------2--------------<Package version="1"> .... </Package>
2---------2--------------<Package version="1"> .... </Package>
3---------2--------------<Package version="1"> .... </Package>
and so on
```

I am trying to update the version inside the XMLdata to 2, like:

```
id--------version-------XMLdata
1---------2--------------<Package version="2"> .... </Package>
2---------2--------------<Package version="2"> .... </Package>
3---------2--------------<Package version="2"> .... </Package>
and so on
```

I am running a query like:

```
UPDATE Tbl
SET XMLDATA.modify('replace value of (/Package[1]/@version)[1] with "2"')
WHERE version=2
```

But in the output I see only the last record getting version changed to 2.
Individual record also I am able to update with:

```
UPDATE Tbl
SET XMLDATA.modify('replace value of (/Package[1]/@version)[1] with "2"')
WHERE id=1
```

But not all records together. I don't understand what is the reason behind this.
I tried to create the copy of Table called Tbl2 and there the query is updating all the record version inside the XML data.
What could be the possible dependency which is stopping the query to change the version attribute value?

Comment: It was a trigger on that table.

Answer (score 1):

`.modify()` is very limited, it allows only one change per call, but this should work as expected. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT,[version] INT, XMLdata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,2,'<Package version="1"> .... </Package>')
,(2,2,'<Package version="1"> .... </Package>')
,(3,2,'<Package version="1"> .... </Package>');

UPDATE @tbl SET XMLdata.modify('replace value of (/Package/@version)[1] with 2')
WHERE [version]=2;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

You could use `sql:column("version")` instead of `2` without a `WHERE` to set all XML-version attributes in sync with the version column of the table in one call:

```
UPDATE @tbl SET XMLdata.modify('replace value of (/Package/@version)[1] with sql:column("version")');
```